# Push notification in matrix sdk

Tags: android

I'm creating an android video calling app using kotlin with [Matrix](https://matrix.org/) SDK's Rest API. Here I need to handle push notification How to send push notification from one user to another in Matrix SDK. The following documentation is not working (giving 404 response)
https://matrix.org/docs/spec/push_gateway/latest